# How to Search Text and fill the value to next cell in Macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of long data with long text. I want to identify the text by finding the word (in column A) and fill the next cell of it with value if its match (column B). I know I can achieve it with formula, but too many conditions. It makes the spreadsheet slow down. How to achieve it with macro? For example:

```
Column A        |  Column B
---------------- -------------
this is apple   |  apple

this is grape   |  grape

this is banana  |  banana

etc.....
```

Comment: So you want the macro to copy the words from Column B and paste in Column A? Can you explain more what the initial case is, and what you want the macro to do.

Comment: it's not to copy but to search text. for example if it contains apple then write down text i define at next cell or cell i define. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim LookFor As String
'This will be a placeholder for the word you want to search for

LookFor = "apple"

On Error Resume Next  
   'in case we could not find the word, we need to continue

Range("A:A").Find(LookFor).Select

If Err = 0 Then
    'if there are no errors, that means we found the word

    Activecell.Offset(0, 1).Value = LookFor
    ' put the same word on the next column, same row
Else
    'there was an error, meaning: the word was not found
    MsgBox "Could not find " & LookFor
End If

'we need to cancel our error detection strategy so that 
' new errors will be reported to the user, otherwise, strange things 
' might happen later
On Error Goto 0
```

Comment: is it possible to add more conditions? I have 12 words to search.